# Command: sudo docker, Error, rundocker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker

I am trying to run:

```
$sudo docker run --rm -it gitlab/gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url "https://gitlab-abc.xxx.com/" --registration-token "vKKyxyyAAAASS--FDF3Z" --executor "docker" --docker-image alpine:latest --description "git_lab_runner_surendra" --tag-list "bdb" --run-untagged="true" --locked="false" --access-level="not_protected"
```

Output Error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\"": unknown.
```

How to make it work? What went wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more context to the question? What are you trying to achieve using OCI?

Comment: I want to run gitlab runner